# 'CREATE VIEW' in SQL Server Express

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-express

I have UDF in SQL Server Express that uses `newid()` and therefore needs a view in order to function.

Where would I create a view using SQL Server Express and VS 2010? Right clicking on views in the db schema and clicking on add new view only loads a visual designer. Also, the SQL editor in VS 2010 does not allow me to add a `CREATE VIEW` statement to the function file. The following is the SQL statement that I need to allow the UDF to have access to:

```
create view getNewID as select newid() as new_id
```

Comment: There are so many parts of this question that make me go `Hunh?`, I don't know where to start. (Okay, I'll go with one) Why can you not use `newid()` directly?

Comment: The use of newid() is prohibited in UDFs since they are non-deterministic. Therefore a view needs to be created

Comment: There are good reasons why a UDF needs to be deterministic. Circumventing these rules isn't going to win you anything, other than undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [SSMS](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7593)
2. Inside SSMS, Open new connection to your database
3. Open a query window (Ctrl-N)
4. paste in `create view getNewID as select newid() as new_id` and hit F5 to cause it to run

Answer (score 0):

The use of `newid()` is prohibited in UDFs since they are non-deterministic. Therefore a view needs to be created.